# Import CSV into table - MySQL [Error Code: 2068]

Tags: mysql, csv, load

I am getting this error :

*Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.*

I checked the SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile' ------ VALUE:ON

Also, I added to the advanced configuration of the connection the following OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1.

I'm using this query

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE   '/Users/hola/testingrow.csv'
INTO TABLE mytable

What am I doing wrong? Im working on a MAC

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are trying to import cannot be read by your SQL user. Update permissions on that file so that it can be read by anyone (chmod 7xx ) or create a local user for the SQL user on your local machine and grant it access to that file. Alternatively you could move that file to a directory which is already accessible by the SQL user.